# Why does Martin's position in his tapestry change over time?

Tags: redwall

In the Abbey of Redwall there is a tapestry that depicts Martin The Warrior of Redwall vanquishing the Abbey's enemies. Over the course of the series Martin's image seems to shift position. I believe it starts out in the bottom middle, but in later books it is describes as being (I think) in the botttom center.

Addendum: In *Redwall* (pub. Ace paperback 1998) pg. 52, bottom right corner. In *Triss* (pub. Philomel 2002) pg. 69, center. In *Loamhedge* (pub. Firebrand 2005) center.

Why is this?

Comment: https://redwall.fandom.com/wiki/Redwall_Tapestry

Comment: The wiki mentions that the tapestry has been repeatedly repaired. Could this explain the moving location of his image?

Comment: @DavidW You could have edited it too ;-) I've now done that and reopened.